# PHP GCP StorageClient get list of directories ( prefixes )?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to get list of all available ( directories ) which called prefix inside GCP storage API , I've read all examples code which available on this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/main/storage/src) by Google dev .

unfortunately i am still unable to list only directories , since the bucket has over 800k directory each dir is for a specific user.

also , when i query the objects its taking too long since the bucket has millions of records , is it possible to make it paginated query since there is `nextPageToken` ?

here is what i am trying so far :

```
try {
                $bucket = $this->storage->bucket('xx.xx.xx');
                $options = ['prefix' => null,   'fields' => '*,nextPageToken'];
                foreach ($bucket->objects($options) as $object) {
                
                $object = $bucket->object($object->name());
                $info = $object->info();
                echo "<pre>" ;print_r($info);
                
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // maybe invalid private key ?
            print_r($e);
        }
```

Comment: Firstly, directories does not exist, it's only a prefix with a / to make it more human-friendly. Anyway, I wrote this article which can help you: https://medium.com/google-cloud/extend-cloud-storage-filtering-with-bigquery-object-table-7ce4a0f75a3d

Comment: thnx @guillaumeblaquiere , i will try to use mongodb instead of mysql for files/prefix references

Comment: Why mongodb? and why are you talking about MySQL?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere google is charging higher than mini vps , if i rent a mini vps just to use it as mongodb data storage it would be more cheaper than google pricing! correct me if i am wrong!

Comment: Maybe, but how will you solve your query-in-cloud-storage-issue with MongoDB?

Comment: i will save references for directories and files , while the physical files on gcs

Comment: Ok, agree,  MongoDB is a great choice. But BigQuery object table is a great one too!